# Simple C++ program: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm trying to compile a simple C++ program in VS Code -- *it's literally just a `std::cout` statement; I can post it but I can't imagine that's the problem* -- I followed the instructions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc). The C++ extension is installed and I have Build/Developer Tools for VS17 and 19 - I opened the respective command prompts and they do exist. I even compiled my simple program from the developer command prompt and everything worked fine.

However, whenever I try to build within VS Code after configuring the default build task using `Ctrl+Shift+B`, I get the `'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
error in the output:

[image]

I thought it might be because the `cl.exe` path needed to be the full path so I changed that in both the `tasks.json` file and the `c_cpp_properties.json` file to no avail. Whenever I just open a separate `cmd` window and manually run the compile commands it works fine too.

The thing I'm scratching my head about is why this window looks different than the window that appears whenever I open a new `cmd` window in VS Code which looks like this:

[image]

I don't know if that matters, but again when I manually compile from this window it works.

It seems like I should not be having this many difficulties. I haven't changed anything at all from the instructions but this simple thing isn't working. The only other thing I could think of was maybe it has something to do with the fact I have developer tools for 2017 AND 2019 installed, but to me I can't understand how that would matter.

If it helps, this is my `tasks.json` file (again, I haven't modified anything from what was automatically generated):

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                "/Zi",
                "/EHsc",
                "/Fe:",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "${file}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I suspect that part of the toolchain is not properly handling (or handing off) a command-line argument that has a space in it to the next tool in the chain.

Comment: The problem is spaces in path of the file you are trying to execute. With that said it's not 100% clear from the redacted output how this happens.

Comment: you **need** to run `code` from the Visual Studio cmd prompt

Comment: @Eljay makes sense. That's the hard part, figuring out what exactly to look at to see if it's the culprit. It is also frustrating because I'm not doing anything crazy, just a simple and normal program

Comment: is there any type of log?

Comment: Did running code from teh vs command prompt helped?